# how to see if all elements in vector are the same?

Tags: c++

I have a `vector` of `vectors`.

How would I check to see if all elements in one of the columns are the same?

I`ve tried to check it with this nested for loop but I'm getting an *out of range error*.

```
void move_bee(vector< vector<insect> > &insects_on_board){
   for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
      for(int j = 0; j < insects_on_board.at(i).size(); j++){
         for(int k = insects_on_board.at(i).size(); k > 0; k--){
            if(insects_on_board.at(i).at(j) == "B" &&
               insects_on_board.at(i).at(k) == "B"){
                 insects_on_board.at(i-1).push_back(bee());
                 insects_on_board.at(i).erase(insects_on_board.at(i).begin() + j);
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I have read about the:

```
if (equal(myVector.begin() + 1, myVector.end(), myVector.begin()) )
```

method but it would not compile for me, I am assuming its because it's a `vector` of `vectors`.

Comment: @DavisHerring sorry fixed that

Comment: @codekaizer sorry fixed it

Comment: And you are sure that the size here `for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)` is 10 right? Because this could be where you are facing the out of range error.

Comment: `insects_on_board.at(i-1)` when `i` is zero

Comment: @HarisNadeem yes the vector of vectors is initialized as size 10

Comment: also `k = insects_on_board.at(i).size()`

Comment: @codekaizer when i is zero there is no "B" in that position, so the if statement should not execute

Comment: @codekaizer whats wrong with setting k = insects_on_board.at(i).size()? im trying to compare the first element with the last element and work my way inwards. if all elements are equal, then execute if statement code

Comment: because a `vector` is `zero`-indexed. eg. if size is 5, valid indices are 0..4

Comment: and most of all, compiler errors should pretty much point you what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The initial value of `k` is off the end: use

```
for(auto k=v.size(); k--;)
```

to loop backwards.

The use of `at(i-1)` must also be wrong, since `i` starts at 0.

Unless your vector is sorted, checking just two elements can’t tell you if they’re *all* equal.

Finally, even if you can’t use a range-for (because of index use like `i-1` and `...+j`), do bind a reference to the element you’re working on, at least at the outer level.  The readability improvement is significant.

Comment: never used auto, but I tried it and it said k didn't name a type? anyways is there a built in function of vectors that compares all elements and checks if they are the same?

Comment: @billybob uh, C++ compiler that treats auto  as C did? it should be something rather old

Comment: @billybob: It’s a C++11 feature; your compiler might require an option to enable that language version.

Comment: @billybob: Feel free to ask a new question about your `equal` approach (with a complete example).